Livewire DataTable: `$this->data` is cleared during `dehydrating`, causing table rows to disappear
Title
Livewire: $this->data is cleared during dehydrating, causing table rows to disappear

Body
I’m working with a modular Livewire component structure that involves a base component (BaseTable.php) and child components. The BaseTable is designed to handle reusable table functionality and render a Blade view (table.blade.php) that dynamically displays the data and columns passed down as properties.
Component Structure

The BaseTable.php component includes shared functionality, such as pagination, sorting, and filters, and provides lifecycle hooks (hydrate, dehydrate, etc.).
Child components inherit BaseTable and must override the following:

getQuery(): Returns a query specific to the child component’s purpose.
$columns: Defines the table columns to be displayed.



Example child setup:
protected function getQuery()
{
    return Model::query()->where(...); // Custom query
}

public $columns = [
    ['name' => 'id', 'label' => 'ID', 'sortable' => true],
    ['name' => 'name', 'label' => 'Name', 'sortable' => true],
];

The Blade file (table.blade.php) uses the data and columns properties of the Livewire component to display a table. The rows are interactive, and clicking one triggers a method in the Livewire component.
The Problem

During the initial mount, $this->data is correctly populated via refreshData() and displayed in the table.
Changing the number of rows per page or navigating works fine, and $this->data updates as expected.
However, when I click on a row, the following happens:

The table rows disappear (no longer displayed on the screen).
logger shows that $this->data is cleared during dehydrating.



This behavior is consistent across interactions involving row clicks, but I don’t modify $this->data explicitly in the dehydrating phase.
Key Lifecycle Details
refreshData()
Called to load data based on the query.
protected function refreshData()
{
    $this->data = $this->getQuery()
        ->orderBy($this->orderByColumn, $this->orderByDirection)
        ->skip($this->page * $this->perPage - $this->perPage)
        ->take($this->perPage)
        ->get();
}

handleRowClick()
Called when a row is clicked.
public function handleRowClick($row)
{
    logger($this->data); // Logs show $this->data is already empty
    $this->expandSubData($row['id']);
    $this->clickItem($row);
    logger($this->subData);
}

@foreach ($data as $index => $row)
<tr class="cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-50 bg-white" wire:click="handleRowClick({{ $row }})">
  {{-- table columns section --}}

Behavior Observed

hydrate behaves as expected: $this->data contains the correct data initially.
During dehydrating, $this->data is cleared for no apparent reason.
Clicking a row results in $this->data being empty and the table rows disappearing.

What I’ve Tried

Verified that no explicit code modifies $this->data during the dehydrating phase.
Added logger in lifecycle hooks to track the state of $this->data.
Tested with a backup variable to persist data, but $this->data still gets cleared.
Checked for unexpected state reset in overridden methods, but nothing modifies $this->data directly.

In the blade, I even called a function with nothing in it and my data still emptied...
Question
What could cause $this->data to be cleared during the dehydrating phase? Why does this issue only occur when clicking a row, and how can I debug or resolve it?

Let me know if there's anything else to tweak!
